# Add a field and change its value with Javassist

Tags: java, oop, jna, javassist

I am trying to modify a class dynamically by adding a field to it and then a value. I could add the field, but never the value and I did not find information about this.

The following code takes a class extending from `Structure` (JNA class) and adds the method `getFieldOrder` and the field `args0`.

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();

CtClass spawnStruct;
CtClass pointerClass;

spawnStruct = pool.get("simple.SpawnStruct");
pointerClass = pool.get("com.sun.jna.Pointer");

CtMethod getFieldOrder;

getFieldOrder = CtNewMethod.make(
                "protected java.util.List getFieldOrder() { return java.util.Arrays.asList(new java.lang.String[]{\"args0\"}); }",
                spawnStruct);

System.out.println("Added method to get field order\n");

spawnStruct.addMethod(getFieldOrder);

        CtField counterFileSpawnStruct = CtField.make("public com.sun.jna.Pointer args0;", spawnStruct);

spawnStruct.addField(counterFileSpawnStruct);

System.out.println("Added counterFile field to SpawnStruct\n");

spawnStruct.writeFile();

Class classSpawnStruct = spawnStruct.toClass();

spawnStruct1 = (SpawnStruct)classSpawnStruct.newInstance();

System.out.println("Created a modified SpawnStruct instance\n");
```

Once the `classSpawnStruct` has the method and the field, how can I access the field and modify its value? Obviously should be a `Pointer` object.

Any idea of how must this be done?

Thank you!
Marc

Answer (score 0):

I did the following ...

**Add a field**

```
CtField f1 = CtField.make("int testVar1 = 0;", ctClass);
f1.setModifiers(9);
ctClass.addField(f1);
```

where testVar1 is the variable i have instrumented...

I also instrument the required methods which needs to access this field....

```
for( CrMethod method : ctClass.getDeclaredMethods( ) )
{ 
   method.insertBefore(" System.out.println( testVar1 ); " );
}
```